# Point cloud Data analysis from ROS bag - Info required

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am asking for information on how to proceed. I am fairly new to ROS environment.

I have ROS bag recorded data with point cloud topics (x,y,z,velocity,intensity). I have to perform analysis on this data.

- First I have  to extract Only the point cloud topics from Rosbag. Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?
- Second take the extracted point cloud topics and be able to either plot or graph (x,y,z,velocity,intensity). Any suggestion on which software/language/platform is best to achieve this. ?

Appreciate all the help I can get here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265036/point-cloud-data-analysis-from-ros-bag---info-required./) by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [rosbag Code APIs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API). This will allow you to isolate messages from specific topics from the rosbag.

You can use either C++ or Python to process your rosbags and point clouds. I'm not familiar with getting velocity or intensity data from PointCloud2 messages but in general I find that if you want more than x,y,z data from the point clouds then it's better to use C++. The Python API for accessing point clouds data is more limited. Check out the [Point Cloud Library (PCL)](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) for processing point clouds.

---

Originally posted by [velveteenrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6196/velveteenrobot/) with karma: 136 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on 2017-06-29**:
Thank you in pointing me to right direction.